# Role based view in VAADIN 7

Tags: java, spring-security, vaadin7

I have an Vaadin 7 application working with Spring and currently there is one ADMIN role that can log in into the system and see all views. Now I need to add another role let's say CO_ADMIN and allow user with this role to view part of views. What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use spring security you can make a helper class with the following methods:

```
public static boolean hasRole(String role) {
    return getPrincipal().getAuthorities().contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
}

public static UserDetails getPrincipal() {
    return (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
}
```

Then you can define what roles each part of your view needs programatically:

```
Panel panel = new Panel("securedpanel");
if (SecurityUtils.hasRole("ADMIN")) {
    //panel.setVisible(false);
    panel.setEnabled(false);
}
```

If you want to secure the whole view, you can enable the `@Secured` annotation in the spring security config xml:

```
 <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />
```

With `@Secured` enabled you can annotate your views like this:

```
@Secured("{ADMIN}")
```

This way if the user navigates to the view, it responds with 403 permission denied. You can extend your navigator to handle this by redirecting to another view or define an errorhandler for your application.